# how to call alloy ui on click function for all elements with same css class name

Tags: javascript, liferay-6, alloy-ui

What I want is that I have few links like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="popup-link">sample Link 1</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="popup-link">sample Link 2</a>
```

and I want to call the static html when user clicks the link. For that I have written a code

```
    AUI().ready(
 'aui-aria',
  'aui-dialog',
  'aui-overlay-manager',
  'dd-constrain',
  function(A) {
    A.all('.popup-link').on('click',
      function() {
         var dialog = new A.Dialog({
              bodyContent: 'Loading...',
              centered: true,
              title: 'Sample Popup Content',
              width: 400,
              height:600
            }
          ).render();

          dialog.plug(
            A.Plugin.IO,
            {
              autoLoad: false,
              uri: '/html/sample.html'
            }
          );

          dialog.io.start();
        });
  });
```

but this does not work, it simply does not call the function when I click the link, I also tried this, but same thing

```
    AUI().ready(
  'aui-aria',
  'aui-dialog',
  'aui-overlay-manager',
  'dd-constrain',
  function(A) {
    A.all('.sample-popup').each(function() {
      this.on('click', function(A){
           .....
           ......
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Felix, what version of Alloy are you running?

Comment: I am using LR 6.1.20 EE, so it must be Alloy UI 1.5.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got why it was not working. I was using the same object "A" in the click function as well.

it should be like this: (have a look at the variable name event)

```
AUI().ready(
  'aui-aria',
  'aui-dialog',
  'aui-overlay-manager',
  'dd-constrain',
  function(A) {
    A.all('.sample-popup').each(function() {
      this.on('click', function(event){
           .....
           ......
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about **AUI** but if you want to achieve same task using **jQuery** you can achieve like this

i.e

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.popup-link').click(function(){
      alert($(this).text());
  });

});
</script>
```

Or

**Using Javascript**

i.e

```
<a href="#" onclick="return theFunction();">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function theFunction () {
        // return true or false, depending on whether you want to allow the `href` property to follow through or not
    }
</script>
```

HTH

Comment: this is perfect, but I am looking for alloy UI as that one is tricky and not working!